# Emergence of “got it sorted”

Tags: slang, historical-change

I grew up in England (in the Midlands, in the 1960s) and if there was some issue or confusion that I had successfully resolved, I would have said “I sorted it out”, or “I got it sorted out”.

I haven’t lived in the UK for 50 years, but, nowadays, from British TV shows, I usually hear “I got it sorted”. Is this new? Where did it come from? Is it a regional phrase that became nationwide, or was it imported from overseas?

There’s a similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/sorted-vs-sorted-out), but none of the answers provided the historical info that was requested.

I’m not asking about the meaning, I’m asking about history, origins, and evolution.

Comment: I hope you can Sort it [Out] by asking here. [[ WordWeb says "Sort Out == Make free from confusion or ambiguity" with "Sort == act or operation which puts things in order" ]] With that , I think "Sort Out" is more apt. Maybe : there is some influence of the Computer term "Sort" which may have not been common in 1960 Schooling ? Maybe : it is less verbose , shorter by a word ?

Comment: Unfortunately this has become a ubiquitous [British Transport Police tannoy announcement](https://www.btp.police.uk/police-forces/british-transport-police/areas/campaigns/see-it-say-it-sorted/) from [AML](https://aml-group.com/our-work/see-it-say-it/) *"If you see something which doesn't look right, speak to staff or text the British Transport Police on 61016. We'll sort it. See it, Say it, Sorted."* There have been large numbers of complaints. Personally I do not mind the final "Sorted" but I feel strongly that the middle phrase should be "We'll sort it out."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, "got it sorted" is originally Scottish, with a couple of 19th century uses recorded.

Google Books and NGrams shows that it has always been far more common to use "sorted out", with this meaning (finished, fixed, resolved), although it is not unusual to use "got it sorted" when talking about getting something put in order, counted, or categorised.

The earliest use I can find without "out" is a letter from the publisher Robert Cadell in 1817: "I have at last got Walter Scott managed - Mr T and I got it sorted this morning" ([Sir Walter Scott](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5WnH5_mmcfwC&lpg=PA143&ots=OiL_yBaLks&dq=walter%20scott%20%22got%20it%20sorted%20this%20morning%22&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q=walter%20scott%20%22got%20it%20sorted%20this%20morning%22&f=false), Volume 1, By Edgar Johnson, p 143)

Google Books has: "He ... said it would do for a day till he got it sorted by the men kept for the purpose at night." (The Scottish Jurist: Being Reports of Cases Decided in the Supreme Courts of Scotland, and in the House of Lords on Appeal from Scotland · Volume 35, 1863)

The verb "sort" has various old Scottish meanings that are relevant: to settle, finalise, agree. Example from 1587: "If he had been present at the first thai knew materis wold haif sorted better." ([DSL](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/sort_v_1))

In English, the OED has from 16th and 17th century England the more restricted but similar meaning "To come or attain to an end, conclusion, effect" e.g. "if their working had sorted." Although it is normally used with a preposition: "sorted to perfection", etc. This relates to the older meaning of "sort": to allocate by lot, or more generally to allocate, and hence to decide or turn out. (sort, v.1, OED, 2022)

Comment: Interesting. If I say “got it sorted” with a Scottish accent, it sounds strangely familiar.